# Expanding a column of integers into a column of ranges from 1 to each of the integers?

Tags: google-sheets

### Prompt

Suppose we have a list of positive integers along column A:

```
 A
---
 2
 1
 3
 2
```

My goal is to generate a list of ranges from 1 to each of the integers in that column:

```
 A                   B
---                 ---
 2 ──────────────┬─> 1
 1 ───────────┐  └─> 2
 3 ───────┐   └────> 1
 2 ───┐   └──────┬─> 1
      └──────┐   ├─> 2
             |   └─> 3
             └───┬─> 1
                 └─> 2
```

**Edit**
There are about 200-300 integers in column A and each of them could go up to 60.

---

### Attempt

I am juggling between these functions with no success so far:

- **Row** - Using `=ArrayFormula(row(indirect("A1:"&A1)))`, I can get each of the desired ranges individually. However, I couldn't seem to nest more array formulas in order to combine them into one column.
- **Sum** and **Offset** - The range corresponding to cell `An+1` starts will start on row `sum(A$n:An)`. Perhaps I can make use of this along with the `offset` and `row` function to calculate my "position" in the resulting column. But I also couldn't quite piece them together the way we need.
- **Rept** - Each integer in column A determines the number of times we "repeat" in the range corresponding to that integer. But this led me to a dead end where I couldn't change each individual items being repeated (so that it counts up the required number of times instead of just repeating one value the required number of times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(IFERROR(IF((IF(row(A1:A50)=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A50)),ROW(A1:A50),TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A50))))<=A1:A4,(IF(row(A1:A50)=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A50)),ROW(A1:A50),TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A50))))& "",))),"")))
```

- Will work upto max(a:a)<=50 and count(a:a)<=50; Will work more than that with modifications below
- Change all `A50` to `A250`,If max(A:A) or count(a:a)=250.

**How it works**

- Creates a virtual `1,2,3...` matrix with this formula:(Here,5 is the max(A:A))

  `ARRAYFORMULA(IF(row(A1:A5)=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A5)),ROW(A1:A5),TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A5))))`
- If the matrix is lesser than given `A1:A4` values, Take only those values with a lollipop.
- concatenate the whole matrix ,split the lollipop and transpose to give your array.

Comment: Incidentally, my max(A:A) is just 60, I'll edit the question to mention this.
Still reading the rest of your answer, hang on :)

Comment: What does it mean when a matrix is "lesser" than a range of value?

Comment: Ohhh, ok wait, please double check if I understood this correctly:  
You first create a matrix with count(A:A) rows and max(A:A) columns and each of the rows are just populated with the `1,2,3,...,max(A:A)`. Then for each row in the matrix, we leave the number (and add a lollipop for the concat&split business) if the column is still less than the corresponding integer in A:A.  I think I got the basic idea now, but still quite lost on how array formula put this all together with the matrix thing, but that's another exercise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73984/discussion-between-irin-thirdwater-and-i-i).

Comment: I don't quite understand the `index(A:A,B2):index(Z:Z,B7)`, where is the `B2`, `Z:Z`, and `B7` coming from?

Comment: Ahhhh this is very neat!
Thanks!